# Loud squeal from washing machine

Tags: washing-machine, noise

I have an old Maytag top-load washing machine, model LA182.    At the end of the spin cycle, it often makes an extremely loud squealing noise, like a car with bad brakes.  I assume there is in fact some sort of brake that stops the drum spinning, and it is either worn or out of adjustment.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_SGNoN5kd0) (caution, loud noise).

How might one go about fixing this?  What would likely be involved in terms of parts and labor?  Given the machine's age and inefficiency, it is probably not worth sinking very much time or money into it, so I am trying to get a quick sense of whether to repair or replace it.